# shifting database in python-django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, postgresql

I am a python-django beginner.

I started making a project with PostgreSQL, but find it difficult to set the configurations and dependencies. Is it possible that I make my whole project in sqLite and then shift to PostgreSQL?

Or I'll have to decide a specific database from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that it is very easy to set up, I would not recommend to start using `sqlite` if your choice would eventually fall into `postgreSQL`.

Django ORM tries to "hide" the [differences](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/) between the database management systems, but it is impossible to be good for everyone:

> Django attempts to support as many features as possible on all
>   database backends. However, not all database backends are alike, and
>   we’ve had to make design decisions on which features to support and
>   which assumptions we can make safely.

`sqlite` has a fair number of limitations, "special" handling and "corner" cases, see:

- [SQLite notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#sqlite-notes)

Note, that if you would not follow the advice - at least, use the latest `sqlite` version, prepare a bunch of tests and aim to a high [test coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) - this would help to decrease the "headache" on the switching the database backend step.

Hope that helps.